# For xml path query returns less records SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server, xml, for-loop, path

I need to generate the following XML structure from my SQL server view for four inspection type. The XML structure is as given below.

==

```
<Form FormIdentifier="Major Approvals (EPIC:EPIC Test)" CompanyCode="EPIC:EPIC Test" CompanyName="EPIC Test" VesselCode="EPBARN" SubmittedDate="2019-05-22T08:00:00" Status="Submitted" ApprovedDate="" ImoNumber="9251121">        
  <VesselName>EPIC BARNES</VesselName>      
  <VoyageNo></VoyageNo>     
  <IMO_Number>9251121</IMO_Number>      
  <SIRE>        
    <SIRERow>       
      <Company__Terminal2>SHELL</Company__Terminal2>        
      <Last_Inspected>2019-05-22T12:00:00+00:00</Last_Inspected>        
      <No_of_Obs>1</No_of_Obs>      
      <Risk_Rating>2</Risk_Rating>      
      <ve_Screening_Yes_No>3</ve_Screening_Yes_No>      
      <Comments>4</Comments>        
      <Expiry_Date>2019-05-23T12:00:00+00:00</Expiry_Date>      
      <Planned_Date>2019-05-31T12:00:00+00:00</Planned_Date>        
      <Planned_Port>SINGAPORE</Planned_Port>        
      <Plannng_Comments>5</Plannng_Comments>        
      <Observations_closed_out2>6</Observations_closed_out2>        
    </SIRERow>      
  </SIRE>       
  <Non_SIRE>        
    <Non_SIRERow>       
      <Company__Terminal1>BP</Company__Terminal1>       
      <Last_Inspected1>2019-05-01T12:00:00+00:00</Last_Inspected1>      
      <No_of_Obs1>1</No_of_Obs1>        
      <Risk_Rating1>2</Risk_Rating1>        
      <ve_Screening_Yes_No1>3</ve_Screening_Yes_No1>        
      <Comments1>4</Comments1>      
      <Expiry_Date1>2019-05-22T12:00:00+00:00</Expiry_Date1>        
      <Planned_Date1>2019-05-31T12:00:00+00:00</Planned_Date1>      
      <Planned_Port1>KERTEH</Planned_Port1>     
      <Planning_Comments>5</Planning_Comments>      
      <Observations_closed_out1>6</Observations_closed_out1>        
    </Non_SIRERow>      
  </Non_SIRE>       
  <Additional_Screening>        
    <Additional_ScreeningRow>       
      <Company__Terminal>EXXON</Company__Terminal>      
      <Last_Inspected2>2019-05-01T12:00:00+00:00</Last_Inspected2>      
      <No_of_Obs2>1</No_of_Obs2>        
      <Risk_Rating2>2</Risk_Rating2>        
      <ve_Screening_Yes_No2>3</ve_Screening_Yes_No2>        
      <Comments2>4</Comments2>      
      <Expiry_Date2>2019-05-22T12:00:00+00:00</Expiry_Date2>        
      <Planned_Date_>2019-05-31T12:00:00+00:00</Planned_Date_>      
      <Planned_Port2>OSAKA</Planned_Port2>      
      <Planning_Comments1>5</Planning_Comments1>        
      <Observations_closed_out>6</Observations_closed_out>      
    </Additional_ScreeningRow>      
  </Additional_Screening>       
</Form>     
=====
```

I have the written following query using for XML path and TYPE to create the above XML file.
it works fine as far as the syntax is concerned but never returns exact no of records. for one or two records it works fine and for more records, it either not generated fully or shows fewer records

```
DECLARE @vsl AS varchar(50) = 'Sea Fortune 1';
DECLARE @imo AS varchar(50) = '9293741';
SELECT 'Major Approvals (EPIC:EPIC Test)' AS "@FormIdentifier",
       'EPIC:EPIC Test' AS "@CompanyCode",
       'EPIC Test' AS "@CompanyName",
       '' AS "@VesselCode",
       GETDATE() AS "@SubmittedDate",
       'Submitted' AS "@Status",
       '' AS "@ApprovedDate",
       @imo AS "@ImoNumber",
       @vsl AS VesselName,
       '' AS VoyageNo,
       @imo AS IMONO,
       (SELECT otmajorname AS "SIRERow/Company__Terminal2",
               inspectedOn AS "SIRERow/Last_Inspected",
               tobs AS "SIRERow/No_of_Obs2",
               riskrating AS "SIRERow/Risk_Rating2",
               pscreen AS "SIRERow/ve_Screening_Yes_No2",
               comment AS "SIRERow/Comments2",
               ApprovalTo AS "SIRERow/Expiry_Date",
               plplandate AS "SIRERow/Planned_Date",
               plport AS "SIRERow/Planned_Port",
               remark AS "SIRERow/Plannng_Comments",
               openobs AS "SIRERow/Observations_closed_out2"
        FROM RptXMLepic
        WHERE vtIMONo = @imo
          AND InspType = 'SIRE'
       FOR XML PATH('SIRE'), TYPE),
       (SELECT otmajorname AS "Non_SIRERow/Company__Terminal2",
               inspectedOn AS "Non_SIRERow/Last_Inspected",
               tobs AS "Non_SIRERow/No_of_Obs2",
               riskrating AS "Non_SIRERow/Risk_Rating2",
               pscreen AS "Non_SIRERow/ve_Screening_Yes_No2",
               comment AS "Non_SIRERow/Comments2",
               ApprovalTo AS "Non_SIRERow/Expiry_Date",
               plplandate AS "Non_SIRERow/Planned_Date",
               plport AS "Non_SIRERow/Planned_Port",
               remark AS "Non_SIRERow/Plannng_Comments",
               openobs AS "Non_SIRERow/Observations_closed_out2"
        FROM RptXMLepic
        WHERE vtIMONo = @imo
          AND InspType = 'NON- SIRE'
       FOR XML PATH('Non_SIRE'), TYPE),
       (SELECT otmajorname AS "CDIRow/Company__Terminal2",
               inspectedOn AS "CDIRow/Last_Inspected",
               tobs AS "CDIRow/No_of_Obs2",
               riskrating AS "CDIRow/Risk_Rating2",
               pscreen AS "CDIRow/ve_Screening_Yes_No2",
               comment AS "CDIRow/Comments2",
               ApprovalTo AS "CDIRow/Expiry_Date",
               plplandate AS "CDIRow/Planned_Date",
               plport AS "CDIRow/Planned_Port",
               remark AS "CDIRow/Plannng_Comments",
               openobs AS "CDIRow/Observations_closed_out2"
        FROM RptXMLepic
        WHERE vtIMONo = @imo
          AND InspType = 'CDI'
       FOR XML PATH('CDI'), TYPE),
       (SELECT otmajorname AS "Addional_ScreeningRow/Company__Terminal2",
               inspectedOn AS "Addional_ScreeningRow/Last_Inspected",
               tobs AS "Addional_ScreeningRow/No_of_Obs2",
               riskrating AS "Addional_ScreeningRow/Risk_Rating2",
               pscreen AS "Addional_ScreeningRow/ve_Screening_Yes_No2",
               comment AS "Addional_ScreeningRow/Comments2",
               ApprovalTo AS "Addional_ScreeningRow/Expiry_Date",
               plplandate AS "Addional_ScreeningRow/Planned_Date",
               plport AS "Addional_ScreeningRow/Planned_Port",
               remark AS "Addional_ScreeningRow/Plannng_Comments",
               openobs AS "Addional_ScreeningRow/Observations_closed_out2"
        FROM RptXMLepic
        WHERE vtIMONo = @imo
          AND InspType = 'Screen'
       FOR XML PATH('Addional_Screening'), TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('Form');
GO
```

my data lies in the view RptXMLepic.
would you please help me where exactly the problem lies.

Comment: The SQL looks OK. Have you checked your nested WHERE clauses, for example does `SELECT * FROM RptXMLepic WHERE vtIMONo = @imo AND InspType = 'SIRE'` definitely return multiple rows as you expect? When you say "...for more records, it either _not generated fully_..." can you provide an example of an incomplete output?

Comment: Very hard to help... This line `AND InspType = 'NON- SIRE'` **might** be a typo. At least I would not expect a blank before `SIRE`. Try to create a [mcve], try to reduce your code to just one or two properties per value, provide sample data and expected output. I'm pretty sure, that the data is not what you expect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake only . the query is perfect after a lot of searching on the net I found nothing. actually what I was doing just copying the XML output from the query window and pasting on some noteapd++ editor. But whole XML text was not getting copied. so finally I have clicked on on the output and it was blah blah! I mean it opened pretty well in SQL management studio only with all the data. sorry guys I am pretty relaxed now ..thanks